# How can I do the same job I do when using wc commands without wc commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

> Problem 2. Write a Bash script which prints a table of counters
> denoting the number of commands that start with each letter in the
> alphabet. Do this for the commands under /usr/bin. For example, under
> /usr/bin if there are 38 commands starting with letter a, 26 commands
> starting with letter b,... and 10 commands starting with letter z,
> then your script will print
>
> - a 38
> - ...
> - z 10
>
> Call this script counter.sh. Exclude commands starting with
> non-alphabetical characters. Use loops and arrays to write this
> script.

---

You can see my homework in the above. Actually I can do this homework using wc -l command. like this:

```
for letter in {a..z}
do
echo "$letter $(ls /bin | grep "^$letter" | wc -l)"
done
```

But I don't want to use wc -l command due to my homework. I have been searching but I didn't find answer. How can I do this homework without wc command. Please help me. Thanks you for helping.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `wc` ? That's how I'd do it (I'd probably use `ls/bin/${letter*} | wc -l` but that's trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash`. Fill an array (`a`) with file names and output number of its elements (`${#a[@]}`):

```
shopt -s nullglob   # see: man bash
for letter in {a..z}; do a=(/usr/bin/$letter*); echo "$letter ${#a[@]}"; done
```

Output (e.g.):

```
a 125
b 43
c 115
.
.
.
x 172
y 9
z 14
```